# define character in rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

All tables and fields created with Rails migrations have `latin1_swedish_ci` collate.
Because my project use russian language, this collation is improper.

Is it possible to use migrations with `utf8_general_ci`?

P.S. My database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  collation: utf8_general_ci
  reconnect: false
  database: my_development
  pool: 5
  username: username
  password: 'heavy'
  host: localhost
```

Answer (score 13):

Here's an example of specifying the collation in your migration:

```
create_table :users, :options => 'COLLATE=utf8_general_ci' do |t|
  t.string :email
  t.timestamps
end
```

Comment: It helps, but in schema.rb I see: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", charset is correct now, but no collation.

Answer (score 1):

Rails doesn't set the collation on the connection (only on the database in a `create_database` call).  The best idea here is to set it yourself in your system's MySQL config file, eg. `/etc/my.cnf`

I actually recommend that you tell MySQL to ignore the client handshake altogether, it's better that the server tells the client which character set and collation to use.  The relevant parts of my MySQL conf look like this:

```
[server]
character_set_server=utf8
collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
skip_character_set_client_handshake
```

If you go this path, just remember to do the same on the server you deploy to.  If you don't know where your config file is for MySQL then run this from the command prompt: `my_print_defaults | grep -A1 "Default options"`  That will give you the config files MySQL will look for (in order).

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't give us anything to go on.  You add that to your `my.cnf`, restarted `mysqld` so it picked up the new conf, then ran a `create_table` migration and you're telling me that it wasn't created with that collation?  If so, maybe you need to drop and recreate the DB as well (I didn't think you'd need to do that).

Comment: There is no difference between running migrations before inserting this lines and after. Tables are in `latin1_swedish_ci` dispite of all...

Comment: This would require an administrator-level access to database server and it is not possible every time. I think the another answer would be better from developer aspect.